# PHP Dev Tools (Eclipse Plugin) -- Installation Error

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pdt

I have already installed WEb Tools, PyDev, and the default Eclipse installation for Ubuntu 10.04 (using "sudo apt-get install eclipe").  I'm now trying to install PHP dev tools plug-in for Eclipse, and I'm getting this error msg:

> Cannot complete the install because of
>   a conflicting dependency.   Software
>   being installed: PDT SDK Feature
>   1.0.5.v20081126-1856 (org.eclipse.php.sdk_feature.feature.group
>   1.0.5.v20081126-1856)   Software currently installed: Eclipse XML
>   Editors and Tools SDK
>   3.1.1.v200907161031-7A228DXETAqLQFBNMuHkC8-_dRPY
>   (org.eclipse.wst.xml_sdk.feature.feature.group
>   3.1.1.v200907161031-7A228DXETAqLQFBNMuHkC8-_dRPY)
>   Only one of the following can be
>   installed at once: 
>       Eclipse XML Editors and Tools 3.1.1.v200907161031-7H6FMbDxtkMs9OeLGF98LRhdPKeo
>   (org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.jar
>   3.1.1.v200907161031-7H6FMbDxtkMs9OeLGF98LRhdPKeo)
>       Eclipse XML Editors and Tools 3.0.4.v200811211541-7F2ENnCwum8W79A1UYNgSjOcFVJg
>   (org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.jar
>   3.0.4.v200811211541-7F2ENnCwum8W79A1UYNgSjOcFVJg)
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: PDT SDK Feature 1.0.5.v20081126-1856 (org.eclipse.php.sdk_feature.feature.group
>   1.0.5.v20081126-1856)
>       To: org.eclipse.php_feature.feature.group
>   [1.0.5.v20081126-1856]   Cannot
>   satisfy dependency:
>       From: PDT Feature 1.0.5.v20081126-1856 (org.eclipse.php_feature.feature.group
>   1.0.5.v20081126-1856)
>       To: org.eclipse.wst.feature.group [3.0.0,4.0.0)   Cannot satisfy
>   dependency:
>       From: Web Developer Tools 3.0.4.v200811190840-7A-8l8Qqcz0HyVgjXUE-iuOYZ9ai
>   (org.eclipse.wst.feature.group
>   3.0.4.v200811190840-7A-8l8Qqcz0HyVgjXUE-iuOYZ9ai)
>       To: org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group
>   [3.0.4.v200811211541-7F2ENnCwum8W79A1UYNgSjOcFVJg]
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Eclipse XML Editors and Tools SDK
>   3.1.1.v200907161031-7A228DXETAqLQFBNMuHkC8-_dRPY
>   (org.eclipse.wst.xml_sdk.feature.feature.group
>   3.1.1.v200907161031-7A228DXETAqLQFBNMuHkC8-_dRPY)
>       To: org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group
>   [3.1.1.v200907161031-7H6FMbDxtkMs9OeLGF98LRhdPKeo]
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Eclipse XML Editors and Tools
>   3.0.4.v200811211541-7F2ENnCwum8W79A1UYNgSjOcFVJg
>   (org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group
>   3.0.4.v200811211541-7F2ENnCwum8W79A1UYNgSjOcFVJg)
>       To: org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.jar
>   [3.0.4.v200811211541-7F2ENnCwum8W79A1UYNgSjOcFVJg]
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Eclipse XML Editors and Tools
>   3.1.1.v200907161031-7H6FMbDxtkMs9OeLGF98LRhdPKeo
>   (org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group
>   3.1.1.v200907161031-7H6FMbDxtkMs9OeLGF98LRhdPKeo)
>       To: org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.jar
>   [3.1.1.v200907161031-7H6FMbDxtkMs9OeLGF98LRhdPKeo]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of PDT is incompatible with the repo version, you might want not to use them for eclipse. You can download an "All-in-one" version from this page : http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/, but if I were you, I'd install the smallest eclipse version available, not using the repos, and then use eclipse installation system (with updates sites) to install pdt, PyDev, etc...

Comment: Which installation would you classify as "the smallest"?

Comment: I used the first method, and I have Perspectives I do not need, such as "Java". One of my colleagues used the second one and he says he has far less useless stuff.  I think he downloaded it from this page : http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.5-200906111540/index.php#PlatformRuntime (Plaform Runtime Binary tab). I just tested it, and there are far less binaries in this quite hidden eclipse download. Enjoy ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Just try to install PDT plugin under "Indigo". Not directly.

Answer (score 0):

In this site, find the section for your eclipse version

http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/Installation#From_Update_Site