# Cant install PDT in Eclipse 3.7

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I'm trying to install PDT on Eclipse but it gives me this error:

> Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
>   Software being installed: PHP Development Tools (PDT) SDK Feature
>   3.0.0.v20110516-1100-77--84_23JBVgSVXO7XGJz0VLa9O (org.eclipse.php.sdk.feature.group
>   3.0.0.v20110516-1100-77--84_23JBVgSVXO7XGJz0VLa9O)   Software currently installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1327184315551
>   (SharedProfile_PlatformProfile 1.0.0.1327184315551)   Only one of the
>   following can be installed at once: 
>       Structured Source Editor 1.3.1.v201108191312 (org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 1.3.1.v201108191312)
>       Structured Source Editor 1.3.0.v201105101529 (org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 1.3.0.v201105101529)
>       Structured Source Editor 1.2.3.v201102102045 (org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 1.2.3.v201102102045)   Cannot satisfy
>   dependency:
>       From: Shared profile 1.0.0.1327184315551 (SharedProfile_PlatformProfile 1.0.0.1327184315551)
>       To: org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui [1.2.3.v201102102045]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: PHP Development Tools (PDT) Runtime Feature 3.0.0.v20110516-1100-7V--F8NcJTTK4UE9TTJJ (org.eclipse.php.feature.group
>   3.0.0.v20110516-1100-7V--F8NcJTTK4UE9TTJJ)
>       To: org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group [3.1.0,4.0.0)   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: PHP Development Tools (PDT) SDK Feature 3.0.0.v20110516-1100-77--84_23JBVgSVXO7XGJz0VLa9O (org.eclipse.php.sdk.feature.group
>   3.0.0.v20110516-1100-77--84_23JBVgSVXO7XGJz0VLa9O)
>       To: org.eclipse.php.feature.group [3.0.0.v20110516-1100-7V--F8NcJTTK4UE9TTJJ]   Cannot satisfy
>   dependency:
>       From: Eclipse XML Editors and Tools 3.3.0.v201103310011-7H7EFZ-DxumTla66ahfUnHfpsz0u5Z92pU4TxSL (org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group
>   3.3.0.v201103310011-7H7EFZ-DxumTla66ahfUnHfpsz0u5Z92pU4TxSL)
>       To: org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui [1.3.0.v201105101529]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Eclipse XML Editors and Tools 3.3.1.v201108102009-7H7EFZ3DxumTlaI6nheRdHo2p1KaDIL1Uz-S3PL (org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group
>   3.3.1.v201108102009-7H7EFZ3DxumTlaI6nheRdHo2p1KaDIL1Uz-S3PL)
>       To: org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui [1.3.1.v201108191312]

I've found a similar error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964004/php-dev-tools-eclipse-plugin-installation-error-help) but firstly it isn't the same version of PDT and secondly I don't want to uninstall eclipse. Is there any other way I can solve this?

Comment: I had the same op and did the same (It works). I would say re-install eclipse.

Comment: FYI: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/243406/

Comment: Thank you very much I'll try uninstalling... It seems there's no other way xD

Answer (score 3):

Try with this update URL site based on PDT 3.0 (needed for Eclipse 3.7):

http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/3.0/milestones/